# Node.js iterate array async

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, asynchronous

I have some code where I iterate through all days of the month and for each day I call a function. The function is promise based and fires a firebase query.

I'm currently using the forEachAsync module (https://github.com/FuturesJS/forEachAsync) but it calls the database function synchronious and whaits for the next() callback.

Here is the code:

```
var daysInMonth = ["1","2","3","4",...,"30"];
var calendarDate = new Date();

forEachAsync(daysInMonth, function (next, calendarDate) {

  //async, calls the firebase query
  privRun.getDisableDates(calendarDate).then(function (disabledDate) {
    next();
  });


}).then(function () {
  deferred.resolve();
});
```

How can I speed this up? Instead of waiting for the last promise to resolve I would like to call them parallel or more than one at a time.

Then I need some kind of .done() function...

Comment: `forEachAsync` doesn't support parallel processing, but recommends alternatives for doing so in its [README](https://github.com/FuturesJS/forEachAsync#readme): "*For cases where you want to loop through batches of items at once (as opposed to strictly one-by-one as forEachAsync does), check out [`forAllAsync`](https://github.com/FuturesJS/forAllAsync) and [`lateral`](https://github.com/FuturesJS/lateral).*"

Comment: Thanks! I think forAllAsync is exactly what I was looking for!